# different behavior with a same application under different Os in a VM

Tags: c++

Here's my setup:
Pc with Windows 10 Enterprise (version 2004),
VMWARE Workstation Pro latest (Version 15.5.5 Build 16285975),
Visual studio 2019 MFC cpp.

I've developed an app with Visual studio 2019 (last version upppdated )with MFC and C++. This app only says "Hello." This application is unsigned. On my PC with VMWARE Wokstation Pro I created two Virtual Machine. The first under Windwos 10 Enterprise (version 2004) and the other on Windows server 2019 (version 1809).
I copy my app on the desktop of each VM.
I have two different behaviors when I launch my app:
On windows server 2019, Windows reports that my app has no author. It's a consistent response (runtime antivirus, blue screen).
In Windows 10 (VM version 2004) my app launches without a problem.

When I launch my app on my wife's (version 2004) PC I have the only behavioral mem in the Windows VM server 2019. Which is cohesive.

So my question is why this difference?

Answer (score -1):

I also faced the same issue while working on my projects. Here the suggestion to find the difference of behavior.

1. Try to get the OS version using your code. The OS version of windows 10 is 10 and 6 for the below versions.So you can check the OS version in your VM as well as your system and if the version result is different ,try to write code based on that.Refer the below link to get OS version source code.
   [OS version sample](https://svsivan.blogspot.com/2020/07/get-os-version-c.html)

2. Insert the log and try to fetch the behavior between your various platforms.
3. Check for the warnings as well as memory leaks in your code.